# Close vote cascades

Tags: discussion

This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24664831/ms-access-combo-boxes-2-the-second-one-is-not-displaying-any-data-please-advis#comment38238859_24664831 has been closed by people who do not have an MS Access badge. The question is perfectly clear to an MS Access user, although it could be stated better, however, the OP is very new and seems to have made a real attempt.

Should new users be given a little more leniency?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144557/bandwagon-effect-in-close-votes

Comment: @Remou You can't close a question as a duplicate of another network site's question. In this case, Meta SO -> Meta SE.

Comment: @Remou [Allow site-specific metas to indicate duplicates of questions on the main meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/175991/165773)

Comment: it's rather a poorly written post, not a real question which I think explains why 5 people found it unclear. There are plenty of those I backed off from answering in the past and instead downvoted and voted to close to make the OP aware he can't just get away with a poor question just because he is new.

Comment: @gnat haha you never gave up on looking for a duplicate

Comment: I use Access, and I wholeheartedly agree with the close.  Your argument is disingenuous.

Comment: No, I'm not accusing you of dishonesty.  I'm challenging your assumption that because the closers didn't use Access, they didn't know what they were doing.  I refute that statement.  *I* use Access, and *I* don't know what he's talking about.  Let's not throw around specious arguments about what someone does and doesn't know, shall we?

Comment: _"The question was completely clear to me."_ Then perhaps you can edit it so that it is clear to others.

Answer (score 12):

If you cut the cruft you're left with a problem statement in the title (*"the second combo box is not displaying any data"*), and a question body containing two queries and a life story.

Not a single word about what this is supposed to do, what actually happens and where OP suspects the problem lies.

So no, that is not considered a good question and I don't think being a new user grants you the option to not show that effort.

Comment: ++ completely agreed. Even though some questions can be pretty obvious to solve(*answer*) we still expect them to be of a good quality. If you can't or are not willing to **edit** and **improve** the question do not expect it to last..